# How does web page scraping function written in js work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

Let's say the js code is included in the page code, which receives the URL and returns the full page code (for this URL).

When I click on the button on my page, this js code will be executed. For example, here [Simple JS Full Page Web Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063847/simple-js-full-page-web-scraping).

If the user clicks on this button, will a request for this URL be made on my behalf (by my IP) or by the user (by his IP)?

Comment: The request will be made by the user machine and by his IP. However, this likely will not work due to cross-domain request limitations.

Comment: Like the answer says, It'll only work if the website you're scraping has CORS enabled. CORS and other security factors make it difficult to do web-scraping purely from a browser. If you want to use JS, consider having a headless browser (puppeteer) run on a server that can perform web scraping and then trigger it by using AJAX on the front-end.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers!

That is, if I want the scraping of pages to occur through the ip of the user of my site, then the page I want to scrape should not have CORS?

Do not tell me, is collecting data on api in this way (via js and user ip) possible? I read somewhere that some sites allow you to do this. For example, if I want to parse aliexpress or pandao like that, can this work out?